How can vector load instructions in RVV1.0 merge vector load signed and vector load unsigned into one instruction?
In RISC-V Vector instructions, there're 2 major versions rvv0.7.1 and rvv1.0. Take load 32 bits as example. In rvv0.7.1, there're 2 instructions:vlwu and vlw, which loads unsigned numbers and signed numbers seperately. In rvv1.0, however, there's only one instruction vle32.
The question is how can rvv1.0 achieve the same effect? Moreover, how can the compiler later tells whether a loaded number is signed or unsigned?


In RISC-V Vector instructions, there're 2 major versions rvv0.7.1 and rvv1.0.

No, there currently is only RVV 1.0. The RVV 0.7.1 you are referring to is a non-standard, non-confirming extension (XTheadVector) used by some XuanTie chips, based on an incompatible early working draft of RVV.

In rvv0.7.1, there're 2 instructions:vlwu and vlw, which loads unsigned numbers and signed numbers seperately


vlwu: loads an unsigned word and unsgined-extends it to the current SEW
vlw: loads an signed word and signe-extends it to the current SEW

Note: SEW=set element width, EEW=effective element width

In rvv1.0, however, there's only one instruction vle32. The question is how can rvv1.0 achieve the same effect?

They don't. vle32 loads 32 bit elements (a word) into a vector register.
It does this regardless of the SEW and doesn't extend the elements. If you want to also unsigned/signed-extend the elements you'll have to use vzext/vsext respectively.
See the "Vector Load/Store Width Encoding" section of the specification:

Vector loads and stores have an EEW encoded directly in the instruction. The corresponding EMUL is calculated as EMUL = (EEW/SEW)*LMUL. If the EMUL would be out of range (EMUL>8 or EMUL<1/8), the instruction encoding is reserved. The vector register groups must have legal register specifiers for the selected EMUL, otherwise the instruction encoding is reserved

So if your have SEW=64 LMUL=2, and you load data with vle32, then EEW will be EEW=32, and EMUL will be EMUL=(32/64)*2=1.

Moreover, how can the compiler later tells whether a loaded number is signed or unsigned?

The assembly instructions don't care about the type. You can happily load some data, do an unsigned max operation on it and then a signed comparison, even with the XTheadVector extension. The signed representation is defined as twos complement, so the behavior is well-defined. Notice how there e.g. isn't an unsigned version of vadd, but there is a signed and unsigned version of vmsgt/vmsgtu, this is because twos complement addition works the same as unsigned addition.

Signed vs. unsigned are properties of data types, not properties of values.  By contrast, for an example of properties of values, positive vs. negative are value properties (of signed data).

Moreover, how can the compiler later tells whether a loaded number is signed or unsigned?

This is backwards.  The compiler/processor doesn't tell us data types.
Instead we tell the compiler by using data types on variable declarations and then the compiler makes the machine code and the machine code tells the processor.
Because the processor is unaware of variable declarations (hence of variable's data types) — it never reads variable declarations, it only ever sees machine code instructions — it has to be told on every usage of a variable what size to use and what type to use (when it matters, like with comparison); this is communicated to the processor within the stream of the program's machine code instructions.
So, each and every time you use a variable, the compiler generates the right machine code for that variable's size & type, and for the operation that is accessing the variable (e.g. to add or compare or read or write).
If you're writing assembly code instead of high-level language, then you don't have variable declarations except in your head and in your comments (modulo some assemblers like masm).
Logical consistency is required, but there's nothing to enforce it in assembly language, except the programmer using the right instruction so the processor does the right thing with respect to data types.
It is a logic error, then to treat the same piece of data as explicitly unsigned if you were thinking of it as signed in your pseudo code or algorithm (or vice versa)1.
(It is also a logic error to treat the same logical variable as a byte in one place and a word in another place.1)
(As an aside, overflow is also a concern of the programmer; the programmer must choose data types & algorithms that will either avoid or handle overflow.  For example, while this is certainly true in assembly language, a language like C won't even try to detect overflow at runtime for ordinary arithmetic.)

1Unless the algorithm being followed calls for it.

Thanks for your reply. That's really helpful. Since I'm writing in assembly code, I'll have to  treat the data more carefully when doing mathematical operations like square root.
